# Arduino Analog sensitivity LDR sensitivity to MIC Sensitivity

Tags: arduino

Can I use the LDR sensitivity code on arduino

int ldrValue = analogRead(ldrSensor);

if (ldrValue <=400){

for my MIC to light a LED on my desired sensitivity?
Example is if I have 3 LEDs I want them to light with my desired sensitivities on each LED

```
    if (MicValue >= 100 && <= 200)
{
DigitalWrite(LED1, HIGH);
}
else if (MicValue >= 250 && <= 350)
{
DigitalWrite(LED2, HIGH);
}
else if (MicValue >= 400 && <= 500)
{
DigitalWrite(LED3, HIGH);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming

- that MIC means microphone
- that you hooked everything up correctly
- that the microphones output signal is of sufficient voltage -> add an amplifier otherwise

Then the answer is YES.